# centrifugal force and radius of its circle

Tags: centrifugal-force

If a point starts to travel through a path of circle, then it will must have acceleration. The only reason behind this, the direction of velocity changes always. We already assumed that the value of velocity will remain constant.

For successive certain interval of time, we can draw the velocity vector. If any velocity vector turned with very small angle, then the base of isotherm will indicate this changes. For one
complete revolution we will get different changes of velocity and this changes can be shown through a figure. Summation of all values of changes we may consider as the summation of bases of polygonal.
The more smaller the arms/sides of polygonal, then this polygonal takes a form of circle of radius '$v$'.
Would anybody like to explain how the radius of this circle will be '$v$'? I have tried a lot to realize that fact but I didn't.

For one complete revolution, total changes of the value of velocity will be equal to the circumference of circle $2πv$. If we divide this value $2πv$ by time for one complete revolution '$T$', we will get the value of acceleration $'a' = \dfrac{2πv}{T}$.
For circle of radius '$R$', period '$T$' can be expressed by $T = \dfrac{2πR}{v}$. In above equation (i.e $a=\frac{2πv}{T}$) by putting this value we get '$a$'=$\dfrac{v²}{R}$.

At the beginning we said, circle of radius is '$v$'. But after some time, we considered another circle of radius '$R$'. This total fact is very ambiguous to me. Would anybody like to clear this fact? How are'$R$' and '$v$' interrelated, if we consider them as the value of radius of circles?

Comment: I have seen one video from khan academy, with the similar concept. You can try searching it.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine two spaces each with their own origin, each with their own circle, one for position and one for velocity.  (Or imagine two sheets of graph paper, draw a point in the middle of each and then draw a circle centered at the point, once for each sheet of graph paper)

In the position space you have a circle of radius $R$ (maybe $R=5$ for your graph paper), and let's say (to be concrete) you start at the point $(R,0)$ at $t=0$, then at time $t=T/4$ you end up at $(0,R)$, then at time $t=T/2$ you end up at $(-R,0)$ , then $(0,-R)$, then finally at $t=T$ you end up back at $(R,0)$. trace a circle that goes in that direction passing through all those points, that's circular motion, and you travelled a distance $2\pi R$ in time T, so your speed was $v=2\pi R /T$.  We are done with that circle.  That's it for the first sheet, we've found the speed given what happened in position.  Now the beauty is that we can repeat the same trick for velocity and find out about acceleration.

Note that your speed $v$ did not change, but the velocity did change its direction.  So since speed doesn't change but the velcoity does change it's direction, the velocity itself forms a circle so we are going to draw that circle on the second sheet of paper.  It must lie on a circle of "radius" $v$, since all velocity vectors of speed $v$ lie on that cirlce.  But while the position circle started at $(R,0)$ and travelled to $(0,R)$, the initial velocity was up in the y direction, so the velocity vector starts out at $(0,v)$ and then as time goes on starts to have a part in the negative x direction, until at $t=T/4$ the velocity points entirely in the negative x direction so at $t=T/4$ the velocity is $(-v,0)$, then at $t=T/2$ it has turned so that velocity is $(0,-v)$, then $(0,v)$ and finally by $t=T$ the velocity vector is again pointing in the original y direction, so the velocity is again $(0,v)$.  Now in velocity space the velocity traced out a circle along this second circle on the second sheet of graph paper.  And the circumference of this circle is $2\pi v$ because the "radius" was $v$ (the speed we got from using the first sheet of paper).  So the acceleration is the change in velocity (circumference of the circle in velocity space of radius $v$ that the velocity vector traced out) $2 \pi v$ divided by the time it took $T$, so $a=2 \pi v$.

Now we have two formulas $v=2\pi R /T$ and $a=2\pi v /T$ and we derived them by the exact same method, we had a vector that didn't change its length and only its direction, always keeping the head of the vector on a fixed circle (that travels by turning left if you imagine looking from above like at a road from a bird's eye view).

We want a relationship between $a$, $v$, and $R$, and we have two equations, but both the equations have a $T$ in it.  Often with equations you can get rid of one pesky variable  and own pesky equation by solving for the thing you don't want and then putting it in the other equation.  So we'll take the first equation $v=2\pi R/ T$ and turn it into $T=2 \pi R/v$, then we can plug that value of $T$ into the other equation $a=2\pi v/ T$ to get $a= 2\pi v/ (2 \pi R /v)$ which equals $v^2/R$, so $a=v^2/R$.